# How would this code example be defined in OO/design pattern terms?

Tags: java, oop, design-patterns

Let's say that I have a ListArray of JDBC Connection objects (connectionsArray). However, let's assume that I need to assign a user's name with each Connection in the ListArray. To do this, I create a sort of wrapper object that contains both a Connection object and a String object in a new object called UserConnection. I then populate connectionsArray with UserConnection objects instead of Connection objects. My question is - what type of OO principle has been observed here and (if applicable) what type of design pattern has been used? To me, it sounds a bit like an adapter pattern, but I am not implementing an interface, which seems to be part of the definition of the adapter pattern.

Here's the code for UserConnection:

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.DriverManager;

public class UserConnection
{
    private Connection con;
    private String user;
    private static final String dbUser = "abc";
    private static final String db = "database1";
    private static final String password = "xxx";
    private static final String url = "jdbc:mysql://xxx.xxx.xxx.example.com/" + db;

    public UserConnection()
    {
        try
        {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
        } 
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            System.err.println(e);
        }

        try
        {
            con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, dbUser, password);   
        }
        catch(SQLException se) 
        {
            System.err.println(se);
        }
    }

    public Connection getUserConnection()
    {
        return con;
    }

    public String getUser()
    {
        return user;
    }

    public void setUser(String user)
    {
        this.user = user;
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't understand the down-vote; is it because the question text is too dense?

Comment: Help me upvote it then

Comment: Make your `UserConnection` class implement `java.jdbc.Connection` and hide whatever the user specifics are inside it, then you've got your adapter pattern, which is really what you have anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is indeed the adapter pattern in action, the adaptee being the JDBC Connection object and adaptor being `UserConnection`. The adaptor pattern doesn't talk about the interface in the Java-sense. The idea is to enable clients to work with both the JDBC Connection object and the `UserConnection` seamlessly.

You've in fact made use of the Object adapter pattern, where `UserConnection` **composes** DBC Connection. There is another case of 'Class adapter pattern', where you could have extended a JDBC Connection object, i.e. `UserConnection` **inherits** JDBC Connection.

Comment: A class cannot inherit from the interface `java.jdbc.Connection`, it can only implement it.  You could extend from an implementation of `java.jdbc.Connection`, though that would be very brittle given the whole point of the interface is to provide an abstract type to depend on thus avoiding tying the code to a particular database driver.

Comment: Thanks for the replies. I have added the code for the UserConnection to make it clearer.